# Rewrite URL with query string .htaccess or route.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

I have developed an application with Codeigniter and

I want to Rewrite my GET Query String from this -

```
https://www.example.com/search?state=American%20Samoa
```

to this

```
https://www.example.com/job-vacancies-in-American-Samoa
```

I am ok to go for any of the solutions either with .htaccess or CI route.php

My current .htaccess contatin

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

#Force https:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


#CI index.php removal

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this way In your controller

```
public function search(){
   if(!empty($this->input->get('search'))){
   $search = $this->input->get('search');
   $joined_search='job-vacancies-in-'.$search;
  redirect($joined_search);
  }   
}
```

> In you routes.php consider if default controller is welcome

```
$routes['(:any)']="welcome/search/$1";
```